# Groovy, how to iterate a list with an index

Tags: arrays, list, groovy, loops

With all the shorthand ways of doing things in Groovy, there's got to be an easier way to iterate a list while having access to an iteration index.

```
for(i in 0 .. list.size()-1) {
   println list.get(i)
}
```

Is there no implicit index in a basic `for` loop?

```
for( item in list){
    println item       
    println index
}
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use [`eachWithIndex`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#eachWithIndex(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
list.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
    println item
    println index
}
```

With Groovy 2.4 and newer, you can also use the [`indexed()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#indexed()) method.  This can be handy to access the index with methods like `collect`:

```
def result = list.indexed().collect { index, item ->
    "$index: $item"
}
println result
```

Comment: great answer, where can I find out about closures like `eachWithIndex` and the types of arguments they take?

Comment: I'd start here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/GDK+Extensions+to+Object and http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections

Comment: Be careful if you need to use `break` or `continue` in such loop

Answer (score 11):

Try this if you want to start index 1.

```
[ 'rohit', 'ravi', 'roshan' ].eachWithIndex { name, index, indexPlusOne = index + 1 ->
    println "Name $name has position $indexPlusOne"
}
```